# How to find the name of the IIS features

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, powershell, iis, scripting

I want to script the setup of a machine with powershell and I have no idea how to find the names of the module. I want to build the same script than the script bellow but for asp.net mvc 3, URL Rewrite 2.0, URL authorization...

I tried to search in google, web plateform installer... Am I missing something ?

Ex :

```
Import-Module ServerManager
$features = @(
   "Web-WebServer",
   "Web-Static-Content",
   "Web-Http-Errors",
   "Web-Http-Redirect",
   "Web-Stat-Compression",
   "Web-Filtering",
   "Web-Asp-Net45",
   "Web-Net-Ext45",
   "Web-ISAPI-Ext",
   "Web-ISAPI-Filter",
   "Web-Mgmt-Console",
   "Web-Mgmt-Tools",
   "NET-Framework-45-ASPNET"
)
Add-WindowsFeature $features -Verbose
iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
choco install -y webdeploy
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open a PowerShell prompt and use the `Get-WindowsFeature` cmdlet.

[image]

I believe this PS module is installed by default on servers. For client machines, running Windows 7 for example, you can install the Remote Server Management Tools - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=7887

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I guess it is not exhaustive, I don't see any asp.net mvc (or .net 4.0 or url rewrite...)

Comment: @rad URL rewrite module is out of band, in a separate MSI. ASP.NET 4 won't available on all OS and sometimes is replaced by ASP.NET 4.5. ASP.NET MVC is not a Windows component at all, when developers deploy it along with their web apps directly.

Comment: The list of features is different for each OS version.  You should run the Get-WindowsFeature cmdlet on the target machine to get the list.

Comment: Hmm my initial question was not about windows feature but IIS features
Anyway if I have a windows server 2012 R2 and I wanna install IIS with .net 4.6, where can I found the correct name of module I need ?

Comment: Most IIS features are installed as a Windows Feature.  If you run the Get-WindowsFeature cmdlet you will see the Web-Server, Web-App-Dev and Web-Asp-Net45 Windows features amongst other.  I believe you also have to install .NET 4.6 which is not available via Windows Features - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49981